# Executar função javascript através da terceira janela

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma janela avô, através dela abro um modal janela pai e através deste modal abro um segundo modal janela filho.
Estou tentando executar um clique com `trigger ('clique')` na janela avô, mas não estou conseguindo, pois só funciona se eu colocar a função *click* na modal janela pai.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Janela modal filha:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ok').click(function() {
        var exec4 = $('.exec-zeraid-card');
        exec4.trigger('click');
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Janela página avô:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.exec-zeraid-card').click(function() {
        $('#box').hide(0);
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/250037/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o que você já tentou fazer ?

Comment: Tente colocar o seu código no [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) e insira o link aqui para que possamos analisar.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema fazendo a seguinte alteração:

```
var exec4 = $(.exec-zeraid-card', window.parent.document);
```